# Wordpress output loop into html columns (two divs)?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a loop through my custom post types.

I want to select 8 posts only, and print out the output into 2 columns, 4 posts each.  I'm not really sure how to approach this.  So far I have:

```
<?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'hh_event', 'posts_per_page' => 8 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                echo '<div class="entry-date">';
                $event_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true); 
                echo date('M j',strtotime($event_date));
                echo '</div>';
                the_title();
                echo '<div class="entry-content">';
                the_content();
                echo '</div>';

            endwhile;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to have your content stored in an array like so:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'hh_event', 'posts_per_page' => 8 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

$columns = array( '', '' );
$content = '';
$i = 0;
global $post;

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $content = '<div class="entry-date">';
    $event_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true); 
    $content .= date('M j',strtotime($event_date));
    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= get_the_title();
    $content .= '<div class="entry-content">';
    $content .= apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
    $content .= '</div>';

    $columns[ ($i % 2) ] .= $content;
    $i ++;
endwhile;

echo '<div class="column-left">' . $columns[0] . '</div><div class="column-right">' . $columns[1] . '</div>';

?>
```

So basically you have an array containing two empty strings. You then assign the content of each column to a variable named `$content`. You then append the value of that variable to the proper part of the `$columns` variable and increment the counter `$i`.

Then just echo the contents of each column to a proper wrapping `<div>` element, or however you are going to separate those into two columns.

Comment: How would you modify this loop to alternate left column / right column on every post (instead of the first 4 being in the left, then moving on to the right)?

Comment: That's the way it should work right now. See the `$columns[ ($i % 2) ] .= $content;` part? This basically says "add the content to the n array element" where "n" is 0 or 1 and this alters with every cycle. Because you have `$i = 0` in the first cycle and `0 % 2 == 0`. In the second cycle you have `$i = 1` and `1 % 2 == 1`. In the third cycle you have `$i = 2` and `2 % 2 == 0`. And so on. Is it working in a different way for you?